# Get maximum datetime out of datetime result set

Tags: sql, datetime, max

I have the following query,

```
SELECT  startTime, lat, lon
FROM table
WHERE category = 12 
AND playerId = 10 
AND CAST(startTime as date) >= (select max(CAST(startTime as date)) from table)
```

the logic is to take lat, lon for the last (maximum) date. So, all lat lon for today. The problem is that I get a set of results because max date is

```
10-7-2019 00:00:00 52.521 113.658
10-7-2019 00:10:00 42.521 103.658 
10-7-2019 00:20:00 22.521 93.658 
etc...
```

(I get many results for the same max date because of different times in the same day. I dont get just one row)

How can I take the max out of the above set? I have to do something like

```
AND CAST(startTime as time) >= (select max(CAST(startTime as time)) from table)
```

on the resulting set to get `10-7-2019 23:59:59 22.521 93.658` . I dont know how to do it. Something like

```
SELECT  time, lat, lon
FROM table
WHERE category = 12 
AND playerId = 10 
AND CAST(startTime as date) AS ABC >= (select max(CAST(startTime as date)) from table) 
AND CAST(startTime as time) >= (select max(CAST(startTime as time)) from ABC)
```

Thanks

Comment: You are taking the maximum date over *all* the data.  There may be no matches for the playerId/category you are filtering on.  I don't know if that is an issue.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use `order by` and `limit`?

```
SELECT startTime, lat, lon
FROM table
WHERE category = 12 AND playerId = 10 
ORDER BY startTime DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

If you want results only on the last date in the data (overall), you can use your subquery or window functions:

```
SELECT startTime, lat, lon
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY date(startTime) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM table t
     ) t
WHERE category = 12 AND playerId = 10 AND
      seqnum = 1
ORDER BY startTime DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

In SQL Server, you would use `SELECT TOP (1) . . .` rather than `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: The first example looks right, and I like it because its really simple. I tried to use it, but I get `incorrect syntax near LIMIT` and I don't know why. It looks like it has the right syntax. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: @codebot . . . Your question is tagged "mysql" and MSQL supports `LIMIT`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, you are right. I removed the mysql tag. I am new to mssql and I dont know the exact syntax differences.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this ..

```
SELECT  startTime, lat, lon
FROM table
WHERE category = 12 
  AND playerId = 10 
  AND CAST(startTime as datetime) >= (select max(CAST(startTime as datetime)) from table)
```

for Example..

```
SELECT  Max(Cast(CreatedOn as datetime))
from TimeSheetJob
```

Result :-

```
2019-10-04 15:52:29.080
```

Comment: @chandjogani Thanks for the suggestion, but I get no results. I should get just one row